# How can I run a process as its owner or become its owner without logging in?

Tags: linux, process, ownership

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489913/674

> cron jobs can run as any user, without that user being logged in.
>
> root doesn’t need to log in to start the init process, thankfully (imagine handling a fleet of thousands of servers and millions of VMs otherwise);

If I want to run a process, with me as its owner, without logging in, how can I do that at both **system/library call** level and  utility level?

If `root` wants to do that, how can it do it?

How can [a service user which can't log in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314725) start a process as its owner or become its owner later?

Is the only way to call `setuid()` or `seteuid()` in the program run by the process?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand the point of the question. Where is the complication or novelty of a user setting up his own crontab?

Comment: `crontab -u user -e`

Comment: A process doesn't have an owner until it's started, so that part of the question should be reworded, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [su options - running command as another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/su-options-running-command-as-another-user)

Comment: >If I want to run a process ~as~ and become its owner without logging in .... The question is now a completely different topic.

Comment: @RubberStamp Without logging in, to start a process as its owner, I will have to start another process first and change to become its owner and then that process forks a process with me as its owner?

Comment: My point was and is, your question seems to have morphed from one topic to another and ... as is... is not well defined or worded.  I think I understand your question *now*, but it may be better worded like: **How can I duplicate cron's ability to start a process as any valid user?** .... And I think the answer is found in cron's source tree ... `do_command.c` ... `static void child_process __P((entry *, user *)), do_univ __P((user *));` ... but this is a simple cursory look.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what this is about, but root can "become" any user by calling `setuid()` &co. When a user logs in, the programs they're using to log in is doing the same -- with the inconsequential difference that it *may* write some useless & untrustworhy garbage to `/var/run/utmp`. `cron` is switching the user without doing that -- thence the nebulous idea that it somehow runs as a user without that user being "logged in".

Comment: @mosvy thanks. Do   a service user  start a process as its owner or become its owner later without logging in, by starting with root and then setuid() to the service user?

Comment: Are you asking “how do I start a program, as another user?”?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes................................................................

Comment: Actually...Login is also not a well-defined concept, only session-manager like `systemd-logind` or `ConsoleKit` cares about that, the kernel, doesn't. There're so many commonly used concept not defined at kernel-level, I think you should know that. Since you can always change userspace apps you use(Yeah, that's why sometimes I say open source sucks), all concept defined in userspace might change with the distro.

Comment: What "service user" do you mean by? Service processes are started by service manager, which is usually fork(), setuid(), exec() , but please notice that after exec(), the code of the service program itself might call setuid() as well, which , of course, also affects the UIDs of service process. [some service manager don't do setuid() but rely on the service program itself].

Comment: @神秘德里克 Is there some system call(s) for login? Does login only refer to using the program `login`? Do `su` and `sudo` count as login? Does `cron` count as login? `sshd` invokes program `login`, so `sshd` is also  login?

Comment: @Tim. No. Only syscall to create threads or process. That's why I say kernel doesn't care about login.

Comment: @神秘德里克 what did Stephen mean by login in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489913/674 then?

Comment: Why do you like to ask the same question again and again? Like I said about daemons, userspace processes might care about that, but may different from human's mind. So please define C before you ask "Is this counted as C?" .Back to your question, by systemd with logind, on Arch Linux. `su` or `sudo` doesn't create logind session, so common answer for this situation is no.  But for human, you get an CLI or GUI or control board or vending machine button or a key of a locker, you logined into the system.

Comment: Usually we use the concept with a (context implied) particular userspace.  Like I said no, with common userspace and configuration of ArchLinux.

Comment: Did you see my comment starting from "Actually…"⁇

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There are 3 ways to change user of a process in Unix.

### 2 system level ways to change user of a process

- if the process has capability CAP_SETUID, traditionally root has this capability (and all other capabilities), then it can use `setuid`, `setreuid`, `setresuid`, `setfsuid`, system calls, to change to any other user. Any other user can shuffle uids: A process has 3 uids, it can move them around, at will: it can swap them, or remove them until it is down to one. It can not add `uids`, unless it has capability CAP_SETUID. In general a process can only loose privileges or move them around, using these system calls. These calls allow the program to continue.
- `exec` a `suid` executable: If an executable file has its `suid` bit set, and if it is of a valid type (not a scripts, not java, not …), then when it is run, its effective user id is changed to that of the files owner. (same can be done for group with `sgid` bit). This is the only way to gain privileges. The current program ends when `exec` is called, it is replaced with the new program, but it is the same process, it also inherits open files (e.g. stdin, stdout, stderr).

`fork` dose **not** change user.
A forked process is an exact duplicate of its parent, with a few exceptions (see `man fork`). In particular the uid, gid, and capabilities are not changed.

### Utility methods

These programs use the 2 system methods described above.

- use `sudo` or `su`:

  - `su` will ask for the password of the other user.
  - `sudo` will ask for your password, but will only work if you are registered in the `sudoers` file.

`sudo`, `su`, `login`, `cron` etc use the 2 system methods. (And will create a new process. The other system methods do not create a new process.)

What does `sudo`, `su` do?

```
#↳ ll /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 155K Sep  9  2017 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

As use can see the `sudo` executable is owned by root, and has the suid bit set (the `s`, where you would expect to see the first `x`).

When `sudo` is run, it runs as root (don't try this, unless you know what you are doing). It then does security checks. Then it uses `set??uid` to become the required user, it then `exec`s (and maybe a fork) the required program.

## Running a process, without logging in

Use some timed start service.

- cron
- at

Send a network message, e.g. a web-server may run a task in response to a web request.

Use automated login: use `ssh` to launch a process, via a script on another machine.

Comment: Thanks. Would like to know more about how "Send a network message, e.g. a web-server may run a task in response   to a web request" starts a new process with a different user?

Comment: I believe root process can drop this capability, I know it's nit-picking, but I think it would be better without mentioning "root has this", after all, capability set in indepent from process UIDs, right?

Comment: @Tim Your (later) edits to the answer are confusing. First of all, a process can never be "not running". Secondly, the whole `Running a process, without logging in, means changing the user of a running process, without invoking the login program. (?)` reads like a question that should have been a comment.

Comment: @Tim additionally, `login` isn’t often involved when logging in; for example, logging in using a display manager, or connecting with SSH, doesn’t involve `login`.

Comment: I reverted @Tims edits, and then incorporated the bits that were useful: changed layout of answer, so it maps better to the question. (there were many bits that were incorrect or misleading).

Comment: @Kusalananda I wrote "changing user of a running process" to contrast to that I am not sure if you can `fork()` a new process with a different user.

Comment: I added some more on `set?id` and `exec`, and added a section on `fork` (fork is **not** a method to change user)