# What differences are between ways to prevent a user from logging in, by passwd and shadow files?

Tags: linux, users

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314732/674

> In contrast to user accounts, service accounts often don't have a "proper" login shell, i.e. they have **/usr/sbin/nologin** as login shell (or, back in the old days, **/bin/false**). Moreover, service accounts are typically locked, i.e. it is not possible to login (for traditional /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow this can be achieved by **setting the password hash to arbitrary values such as * or x**).

It seems to give several ways to prevent a user from login.

- the shell field of `/etc/passwd`: `nologin`, `/bin/false`, /bin/true`,`/dev/null`;
- the password field of `/etc/shadow`: `*` or `x`

What are the differences between their purposes? Do they all achieve the same purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: If the purpose is to prevent the user from logging in then yes, they all achieve the same purpose.

Answer (score 3):

They are somewhat different. A user with a “bad” password hash may still log in if something allows him to log in without a password, for example with SSH and an authorized key. But that’s impossible without a valid shell.

On the other hand, there are some situations were a user may be granted some access without a shell (I’m thinking about an IMAP or SMTP server). Then, a user with a “good” password hash may use the service, even is he has no valid login shell.

Comment: Thanks. " a user with a “good” password hash may use the service, even is he has no valid login shell."  How does it use the service?

Comment: @Tim With another computer and a dedicated client software, such as Thunderbird for IMAP or SMTP services.

Answer (score 1):

Just because there are multiple ways to do things, does not mean there was a real purpose as to why. There are some minor differences between system users and normal users.

`/usr/sbin/nologin` is a simple "shell" that was designed to deny access by exiting immediately. Any program can be run as a shell (as long as it is listed in /etc/shells), and if the program simply exits right away then the user will have no access to the system. This is why something like `/bin/false` also works.

Using an asterisk for a password in the shadow file is just how linux represents a locked account password. If you run `passwd -l username` as root, it will lock the account using this method.

Another method is to expire the account by setting the expire date to 1. This can be done by running this:

```
usermod -L -e 1 username
```

Comment: Note for any program to be used as a shell, it must be listed in `/etc/shells`

Comment: @ivanivan updated post to inlude this, thanks

Comment: You do not need to list a shell in `/etc/shells` for it to be used.  Some applications may look in there and not present it as an option, but `/usr/local/bin/foobarbaz` can be used as a login shell without it being listed.   Indeed, there are use cases where you _don't_ want it; eg some FTP servers will only permit access if the login shell is listed, so putting `nologin` in `/etc/shells` may prevent `ssh` access but _permit_ FTP access!

Comment: Note that `*` in the crypt field means "no valid password".  An `!` means locked; from `man 5 shadow`... _A password field which starts with a exclamation mark means that  the password is locked. The remaining characters on the line represent the password field before the password was locked_

Comment: @StephenHarris I guess I should've specified - shell must be in `/etc/shells` if you change to it using `chsh`.  If the `root` user is simply editing `/etc/passwd` then you are correct, doesn't need to be in the shells file.