# !! versus * in /etc/passwd

Tags: login, passwd

My (admittedly dated) understanding of unix is that in /etc/passwd if the second field is 'x' then the identity can login with a passwd that matches a hash found in /etc/shadow.

However, when I list /etc/passwd I see that all the identities are marked with an 'x' including those that should not be able to login. In the /etc/shadow file, the no-login entities have a double bang "!!" in the hash field whereas the loginable users have the expected hash.

So, I presume this double bang convention is some alternative to the old (?) mechanism of using '*' to mark no-login users. Why is the old method no longer used?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46514/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492112/117549

Comment: This should be _easily_ checked against the `passwd(5)` and `shadow(5)` manuals on your system (whatever it happens to be).  Note that many Unix systems don't even use a "shadowed password file" (e.g. BSD systems).

Comment: This is a question about field #2 in `/etc/passwd`, not about field #2 in `/etc/shadow`, and so does not duplicate that.  And I am sad to report, Kusalananda, that this is a case where [the manual page for `passwd(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/passwd/passwd.5.en.html) is misleading to the point of being wrong, as you can see.